# Prove properties of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$, and use them to show $(\sin x)^{\cos x} > (\cos x)^{\sin x} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Given $$f(x)={\ln x \over x}, x>0$$
>
> **I)** Find the monotony of $f.$
>
> **ΙΙ)** Calculate the following integral: $$\int_1^2{\ln x \over x}{dx}$$
>
> **IIΙ)** Find the domain of $f$ and, then, show that the equation $$3f(x)=1$$ has got exactly two positive roots$.$
>
> **IV)** If $x_1,x_2 (x_1<x_2)$ the roots of question **II**. Show that exists $ξ\in(x_1,x_2)$ such as that $$3f(ξ)+3ξf'(ξ)=1.$$
>
> **V)** Solve at $(0,{π\over 2})$ the inequality $$(\sin x)^{\cos x} > (\cos x)^{\sin x}.$$

**Personal work:**

**I)** $f$ is increasing at $(0,e]$ and decreasing at $[e,+\infty)$. Also, $e$ is the global maximum of $f$. $f(e)={1\over e}$

**II)** Let $u=\ln x$ hence $du=\frac {dx}{x}\iff xdu=dx$

The integral changes to $$\int_0^{\ln2} udu=\frac {u^2}{2}=\frac {(\ln 2)^2}{2}$$

**III)** The domain of $f$ is: $(-\infty,{1 \over e}]\cup[e,+\infty)=[e,+\infty)$

I've tried solving for $f(x)$ so this is what I got: $$3f(x)=1\iff f(x)={1\over 3}\iff{\ln x\over x}={1\over 3}\iff 3\ln x=x\iff\ln x={x\over 3}\iff e^{\ln x}=e^{x\over 3}\iff x=e^{x\over 3}.$$
And then I could get to nowhere. Since all the questions are linked to each other, if question **III** remains unsolved, thus, questions **IV** and **V** cannot be solved.

**IV)** I've thought of using Rolle's theorem since all the conditions are met. I chose Rolle over Bolzano because the equation has a derivative in it. Also, another idea would be that I find the anti-derivative of $$3f(ξ)+3ξf'(ξ)$$ and then let that be a function $g(x)$ and apply either Bolzano's theorem or Rolle's theorem.

**V)** I really have no idea about connecting $f(x)$ with either part of the inequality.

Comment: Do you really mean equation II?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's how the exercise states it.

Comment: I think they mean the equation $3f(x)=1$

Comment: The equation II is not an equation, but an integral!

Comment: I know it's an integral but re-read my post and, please see that everything is alright.

Comment: I think it is a typo, the question is senseless

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The equation $$3f(x)=1$$ is equivalent to $$3\ln(x)-x=0$$ now define $$g(x)=3\ln(x)-x$$ for $x>0$ and use calculus.$$g'(x)=\frac{3}{x}-1$$

Comment: $g$ strictly increasing at $(0,3]$ and strictly decreasing at $[3,+\infty)$. It's obvious that $x_1,x_2\in(0,3]\cup [3,+\infty)$ but how can I prove that? By saying: 

When $$0<x<3 \Rightarrow_{g'(x)>0}g'(x)<g'(3)\Rightarrow g'(x)<0$$

When $$x>3\Rightarrow_{g'(x)<0}g'(x)<g'(3)\Rightarrow g'(x)<0.$$?

Answer (score 0):

Your answers for **I)** and **II)** are fine.

For **III)** the domain of $f$ is $(0,+\infty)$ and, by your answer to question **I)**, $f$ is strictly increasing in $(0,e]$ and strictly decreasing in $[e,+\infty)$.  Note that $f(e)=1/e>1/3$. Moreover 
$$f(1)=0<1/3\quad\text{and}\quad f(e^2)=2/e^2<1/3.$$ Now use the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and the fact that $f$ is strict monotone to show that the equation $f(x)=1/3$ has exactly one solution $x_1$ in $(1,e)$ and another one, $x_2$, in $(e,e^2)$.

For **IV)** the idea of using Rolle's theorem is good. Let $x_1<x_2$ such that $3f(x_1)=3f(x_2)=1$ (they exists by question **III)** and consider the new function 
$$F(x):=x(3f(x)-1)=3xf(x)-x$$
(which is the anti-derivative of $3f(x)+3x f'(x)-1$). Then $F(x_1)=F(x_2)=0$ and by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), there is $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that 
$$0=F'(\xi)=3f(\xi)+3\xi f'(\xi)-1.$$

Question **V)** is related to question **I)**. Note that in $(0,\pi/2)$,
$(\sin x)^{\cos x}>(\cos x)^{\sin x}$
is equivalent to
$$f(\sin(x))=\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}>\frac{\ln(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}=f(\cos(x)).$$
Since by **I)** $f$ is strictly increasing in $(0,1)$, it follows that it suffices to solve $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$.

Comment: Regarding **IV** why did you use "$3f(ξ)=1$" and then let $F(x)=x(3f(x)-1)$?

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis I am using $3f(x_1)=1$ and $3f(x_2)=1$ and I define a NEW function $F$. I am not using $3f(ξ)=1$.

Comment: Why did you use $1$ and $e^2$ in question **III**? I'm trying to think like you but I guess at some parts I miss it.

Comment: They are points, one less than $e$ and the other greater than $e$ where it is easy to evaluate $f$ and compare the value with $1/3$. You can try other points or evaluate the limit of $f$ as $x\to 0^+$ and as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: @AlexanderVoliotis Are you still interested in your question? Any further doubt?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- Just to solve **V**
$$\boxed{(\sin x)^{\cos x} > (\cos x)^{\sin x} \space;\space\space x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
Let $$g(x)=(\sin x)^{\cos x}\\h(x)=(\cos x)^{\sin x}$$
We have $$\begin{cases}g(0)=0\text{ and } g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1\\h(0)=1\text{ and } h\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow g\text{ is increasing and } h \text{ is decreasing }$$
Since $\sin(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ we solve
$$(\sin x)^{\cos x} = (\cos x)^{\sin x}$$ which clearly has the solution $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ so we finish with the solution
$$\color{red}{\dfrac{\pi}{4}\lt x\le \dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$